How to prove $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\langle f(t)f(t+s)\rangle\cos(a s)ds=a^2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\langle\dot{f}(t)\dot{f}(t+s)\rangle\cos(as)ds$?
Denoting the time derivative of $f$ by by $\dot{f}$, I want to prove equation (2.96)  given here:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \langle f(t) f(t+s) \rangle \cos(a s) ds = a^2 ~\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \langle\dot{f}(t) \dot{f}(t+s) \rangle \cos(a s) ds$$
My first guess was to write
$$\dot{f}(t) = \lim_{\Delta s \to 0} \frac{f(t+ \Delta s) - f(t)}{\Delta s},\quad \dot{f}(t+s) = \lim_{\Delta s \to 0} \frac{f(t+s+ \Delta s) - f(t+s)}{\Delta s}$$
but as you can see, this doesn't lead to anywhere. How can one prove this equality?

Sorry! What do you mean by $\langle f, g \rangle$?

I think it stands for "long time average" (here t and s are time variables).

What is the definition of this "long time average"?

I'd say it is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty,dt,f(t)f(t+s)$ so the integral in question is actually a double integral. (And it's possible of course that the $t$ integral is somehow done in a more complicated way if that is required for convergence...)

@Mike look at the equation (2.96), I think the $a^2$ should be in the LHS of the equation

If we interpret the notation $\langle f(t) f(t+s) \rangle$ as the autocorrelation $R_{ff}(s)$ of a real continuous function $f(t)$:
$$
 \langle f(t) f(t+s) \rangle = R_{ff}(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\,dt\,f(t)f(t+s)
$$
then the question is in fact about its Fourier transform, which is the power spectral density function $S_{ff}(a)$:
$$
S_{ff}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}ds\ e^{-ias}\ \langle f(t) f(t+s) \rangle
$$
To be precise, we need the real part of it:
$$
\text{Re}\,S_{ff}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}ds\ \cos(as)\ \langle f(t) f(t+s) \rangle
$$
Since the power spectral density is just the square of the Fourier transform of $f$:
$$
S_{ff}(a) = |\tilde f(a)|^2 = 
\Big|{\small \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}}ds\ e^{-iat}\ f(t)\ \Big|^{\large 2},
$$
and we know that the Fourier transform of $\dot f$ is just the Fourier transform of $f$ multiplied by $i$ times the frequency:
$$
  {\small \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}}ds\ e^{-iat}\ \frac{df(t)}{dt}
= ia {\small \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}}ds\ e^{-iat}\ f(t),
$$
it follows easily that
$$\begin{align}
  S_{\dot{f}\hspace{-2pt} \dot{f}}(a) &= a^2\, S_{ff}(a) \tag{1}
\\[5pt] \Rightarrow
 a^2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \langle f(t) f(t+s) \rangle \cos(a s) ds &= ~\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \langle\dot{f}(t) \dot{f}(t+s) \rangle \cos(a s) ds
\end{align}$$
which is almost the expression the question asked for, only the $a^2$ is on the other side.
So it appears that in the question there might be an error, or something different than the autocorrelation is meant with $\langle f(t) f(t+s) \rangle$. It seems to be a typo in OP's text, since Eq. (2.96) in the reference link states that $S_\omega(\omega) = \omega^2 S_\phi(\omega)$, which is the same as Eq. $(1)$ above.

Setting
$$
F(s) = \langle f(t)f(t+s) \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)f(t+s) \ dt
$$
we have that, if $f$ has a certain decay such that $F$ also has, we can integrate by parts and then
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(s)\cos{(as)} \ ds &= -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F'(s)(-a^{-1}\sin{(as)}) \ ds = a^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F'(s)\sin{(as)} \ ds \\
&= -a^{-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F''(s)a^{-1}\cos{(as)} \ ds = -a^{-2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F''(s)\cos{(as)} \ ds,
\end{align*}
now notice that, again, integrating by parts (and assuming we can differentiate under the integral sign)
$$
F''(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)f''(t+s) \ dt = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(t)f'(t+s) \ dt.
$$
Plugging this into the other equality we have the equation desired.

You integrated by parts and took the derivative $F'(s)$, so you should have taken the primitive of $\cos as$, so that would give $1/a$ instead of $a$ and in the end the $a^2$ would end up at the wrong side. (See my answer, where the same happens, so this points to a possible typo in the question, or to something else of course...)

@JosBergervoet You are right, just made an edit

But now you don't get the equation that was required (even though you say you do at the end!) Could you please confirm that we actually get a different equation, with $a^2$ on the other side than what was written in OP's question?

I just looked at the reference of the OP and this is actually the correct equality

Your use of "this" is ambiguous. Is OP's claimed equation correct or is the (different) result derived by you and me correct?

@JosBergervoet The different result is the correct one

OK yhanks (sorry for bothering you I probably should have looked it up myself...)
